# SSRS Report builder LENGTH expression & size specific field

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I'm trying to build a bank file using SSRS report builder (3.0). I'm running into two issues:

1. I'm trying to get a length expression to work on a check number field but `LEN(Field)` doesn't work (returns 4 as the value regardless of the actual length of the field).

And `LENGTH(Field)` gives me an error:

> The Value expression for the textrun 'Textbox15.Paragraphs[0]. TextRuns[0\' contains an error: [BC30451] Name 'LENGTH' is not declared*

2. The only reason why I'm even trying to get #1 to work is because I need to have one of the fields on the bank file have a constant length. Regardless of the check number, I need to make sure this field is always at 14 characters with leading zeros. I thought the best way to do this is to do a switch statement and add the number of appropriate zeros in depending on the size of the check number field.

Thanks for the help.

Edit: using a SQL server DB

Answer (score 3):

**For the length issue:**

There are two ways to get string length

Using the LEN function

```
= LEN(Fields!myfield.Value)
```

Using the length property

```
= Fields!myfield.Value.Length
```

If your field is not a string, try converting first by using the Cstr function

```
= LEN( Cstr(Fields!myfield.Value) )
= Cstr(Fields!myfield.Value).Length
```

**For the formatting issue:**

For numeric fields set the cell format expression to have as many zeros as required eg. for 14 digit numbers

```
= "00000000000000"
```

Comment: The problem with this is that sometimes the check number is 3 digits, so I'll need 11 zeros for those. Other times the check number is 5 digits, so I'll need 9 zeros for those.

Comment: Got it, the problem was that I needed to convert to a string. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know on which database you are working if you are using sql server then try LEN
function and LENGHT in oracle.

I think you first convert it into integer if it's character and then try len function.

Comment: Using a SQL Server DB. The check number field is already an integer and LEN isn't working. Does LEN only work for integers or strings?

Comment: LEN work on both string and integer but I thought that if char data type then it's show left padding zero like as this : - 
 '000000006211',
 '000000006212',
 '000000006213'